# Popup after page is loaded instead of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, timeout, popupwindow

**SOLVED**

...
..
.

.
..
...

**Hello**,
i searching around on the internet and can't find a code, that show's a popup after page is loaded. I found one popup template, but it's with button to open a popup window, and can't write a code to open after pages is loaded.. Can some help me? :/ Sorry for my english :x

Popup-Window-Template with examples and source's: [HERE](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

The code:

```
<ul class="examples">
    <li class="success">
        <div class="ui">
            <button>Try me!</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
document.querySelector('ul.examples li.success button').onclick = function(){
    swal({
        title: "Hi,",
        text: "Thanks",
        timer: 2000,
        showConfirmButton: false
    });)
};
</script>
```

Comment: call `swal()` outside the click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shyju's code will work correctly if you are using JQuery.
If you are not, than you can try below:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        swal({
            title: "Hi,",
            text: "Thanks",
            timer: 2000,
            showConfirmButton: false });
    }
</script>
```

The difference between window.onload vs $(function(){}) is:

- $(function)({}): executed once the DOM frame loading is finished.
- window.onload: executed after both the DOM frame and all resources(ex:image) loaded completely.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply!

Answer (score 1):

Call your method on the [document `ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

`ready` event will be executed when the DOM elements are loaded.

```
$(function(){

    alert("DOM loaded. Hopefully swal method does not have any other script errors");

    swal({ title: "Hi,",  text: "Thanks", timer: 2000, showConfirmButton: false });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply!